# Running python file using crontab doesn't work on linux

Tags: python, linux, cron, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried to run telegram bot during certain hours (11pm - 1am)

my crontab -e configurations:

```
* 23,0,1 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Desktop/welcomebot/bot.py
```

When I actually tried 23-1, the error kept appearing so I tried that way

when I pressed run button of the file thru the vscode, it still runs on telegram when it was beyond the assigned time.

and when I fix the time into the current time and saw if the file works without pressing the run button of the editor. It didn't work.

I don't know what's the proper way of doing this work

somebody please help

thank you

Comment: You mentioned error, please edit post and add error message. 
Maybe you have some path in python file that are not working properly when file is ran by crontab.
You can always redirect command output to file using  bash redirection to check python output.

Comment: @userkk The only error he mentioned was from using `23-1` as the hours specification in the crontab, which he fixed by changing to `23,0,1`.

Comment: Note that this runs from 11pm to 1:59am, not 11pm to 1am.

Comment: Redirect the output of the script to a file so you can see if it's getting errors. Add `>>/home/user/bot.log 2>&1` to the end of the line.